# Filter message body by using Google App Scrip to put in spreadsheet table

Tags: google-apps-script, automation, gmail, spreadsheet

I'm receiving emails from bank on every transaction based on transaction data in email body, see example below.

[image]

Now, I want to separate data to transfer in my spreadsheet like the value next to branch code should be in last row of column A, and branch code on column B, slip no on Column C, and so on.

Below is my code which I try:

```js
//function to seprate and filter data
function parseEmail(message){
    let parsed = message.replace(/Branch Code /g,'')
        .replace(/Branch Name /g,'')
        .replace(/Slip No /g,'')
        .replace(/\n*.+:/g,',')
        .replace(/^,/,'')
        .replace(/\n/g,'')
        .split(',');

    let result = [0,1,2,3,4,6].map(index => parsed[index]);
    Logger.log(result[0]);
    return result;
}

// main function to search email
function testforemails0003(){
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Emails");
  var Gmail = GmailApp;
  var lasttime = sheet.getRange("Z1").getValue();
  Logger.log(lasttime);
  var cdate = new Date();
  var ctime = cdate.getTime();
  var qDate = sheet.getRange("Z3").getValue();
  Logger.log("QDATE IS " + qDate);

  // SEARCH EMAIL
  var query = 'subject: subject, after:' + Math.floor((qDate.getTime()) /1000);
  var threadsNew = Gmail.search(query);
  Logger.log(threadsNew.length);
  
  //loop all emails
  for(var n in threadsNew){
    var thdNew  = threadsNew[n]; 
    var msgsNew = thdNew.getMessages();　
    var msgNew = msgsNew[msgsNew.length-1];
  // GET ATTACHMENT
    var bodyNew = msgNew.getBody();
    var plainbody  = msgNew.getPlainBody();
    var subject = msgNew.getSubject();
    var Etime = msgNew.getDate();
    var attachments = msgNew.getAttachments();
    var attachment = attachments[0];
    
    Logger.log(Etime);
    Logger.log(subject);
    parseEmail(plainbody);
  }
    
    Logger.log(threadsNew.length);
    var lastscantime = threadsNew[0].getLastMessageDate();
    var lastsubject = threadsNew[0].getFirstMessageSubject();
    Logger.log(lastscantime);
    Logger.log(lastsubject);
    sheet.getRange("z3").setValue(lastscantime);
    
}
```

The problem is I want all values in a separate array so put them in separate columns.

My output is all values in one array, I want all fields separated to set in a spreadsheet.

My output is:

```
[0123
abc BR KARACHI
Slip No 0000242
BL Number abc123456789
Type Of Payment 04
Customer Name abc corporation
Payer Bank
Payer Bank Branch
Transaction Type Cheque
Amount 100, 000.00
Posting Date 27-08-2021
Value Date 27-08-2021
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,  consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo
ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis
parturient montes,  nascetur ridiculus mus. Donec quam felis,  ultricies nec,  pretium quis]
```

Comment: what does your code return and what excactly do you want it to look like?

Comment: my code returns the output of my email body in one array, I want all in separated arrays

Comment: I would need to see the structure of both if you want me to be able to help. You can redact any private data, but the structure has to be apparent and preferably pasted as code and not a screenshot

Comment: OK, LET ME MAKE A DUMMY DATA EMAIL AND SHARE WITH YOU.

Comment: Can you share the structure of the end-result you are expecting as well? @MehdiAbbas

Comment: I want all fields are in separate array like this:

[[0123]
[abc BR KARACHI]
[0000242]
[abc123456789]
[04]
[abc corporation]]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are too much to guess, so just a guess...

```js
var message =

`Branch code 0123
Branch name abc BR KARACHI
Slip No 0000242
BL Number abc123456789
Type Of Payment 04
Customer Name abc corporation
Payer Bank
Payer Bank Branch
Transaction Type Cheque
Amount 100, 000.00
Posting Date 27-08-2021
Value Date 27-08-2021
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,  consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo
ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis
parturient montes,  nascetur ridiculus mus. Donec quam felis,  ultricies nec,  pretium quis`


function parseEmail(message) {

  var replaces = [
    'Branch code',
    'Branch name',
    'Slip No',
    'BL Number',
    'Type Of Payment',
    'Customer Name',
    'Payer Bank',
    'Payer Bank Branch',
    'Transaction Type',
    'Amount',
    'Posting Date',
    'Value Date'
  ];

  return message.split('\n').slice(0, replaces.length)
    .map((c,i) => c.replace(replaces[i], '').trim());

}

console.log(parseEmail(message));
```

You can append the parsed array as a new row to the sheet this way:

```
SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().appendRow(parseEmail(message));
```

Result:

| A | B | C | D | E | F | G | H | I | J | K | L |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 123 | abc BR KARACHI | 242 | abc123456789 | 4 | abc corporation |  |  | Cheque | 100, 000.00 | 27-08-2021 | 27-08-2021 |

Comment: thank you very much, you got my point, just a little bit 1 question pls, if I want to pick only 1 field i.e: the amount which is 100,000.00 in this above example, how to get this? I tried with 

console.log(parseEmail(message[9]));

but failed.

Comment: You're welcome. Try `console.log( parseEmail(message)[9] )`

Comment: oh sorry, it was my typo error. Thanks a lot.