# Google App Script problem in Loop emails when conversation length are long

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, automation, gmail

Reference to the previous question to [Filter Gmail body and paste in Spreadsheet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68952307/filter-message-body-by-using-google-app-scrip-to-put-in-spreadsheet-table)

I had created below a google app script and set a trigger for after every 5 minutes:

```js
function GetEmailsData(){
    // SKIP TO OUT OF OFFICE HOURS AND DAYS
    var nowH=new Date().getHours();
    var nowD=new Date().getDay();
    if (nowH>19||nowH<8||nowD==0) { return }
    

    // START OPERATION
  var Gmail = GmailApp;
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
  var MasterSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Master");
  var index = 2;
  var aa = 0; // count already update entries
  var na = 0; // count not update entries
  var lasttime = MasterSheet.getRange("Z1").getValue(); // in spreadsheet i record the last time of email scanned, so next trigger will search after that
  Logger.log(lasttime);
  var cdate = new Date();
  var ctime = cdate.getTime();
  var qDate = MasterSheet.getRange("Z1").getValue();
  Logger.log("QDATE IS " + qDate);
  
  //problem # 1: from filter is not working.
  // SEARCH EMAIL
  var query = 'from: email id, subject: email subject, after:' + Math.floor((qDate.getTime()) /1000);
  var threadsNew = Gmail.search(query);
  Logger.log(threadsNew.length);


  //loop all emails
  for(var n in threadsNew){
    var thdNew  = threadsNew[n]; 
    var msgsNew = thdNew.getMessages();　
    var msgNew = msgsNew[msgsNew.length-1];
  // GET ATTACHMENT
    //var bodyNew = msgNew.getBody();
    var plainbody  = msgNew.getPlainBody();
    var subject = msgNew.getSubject();
    var Etime = msgNew.getDate();
    //var attachments = msgNew.getAttachments();
    //var attachment = attachments[0];
    
    Logger.log(Etime);
    Logger.log(subject);
    //Logger.log(plainbody);
    var tdata = plainbody.trim();
    var data = parseEmail001(tdata);
    //Logger.log(data);

    // First Check Email Date
  var newdate = new Date();
  var dd = newdate.getDate();
  var mm = newdate.getMonth() + 1;
  var yyyy  = newdate.getFullYear();
  var cd = dd + "-" + mm + "-" + yyyy
  //Logger.log(new Date());
  //Logger.log(cd);
  if (Etime.getDate() != dd) {return}

  // first check current sheet exist or not 
  // DATE DECLARATION IS  ABOVE
  var itt = ss.getSheetByName(cd); 
  if (!itt) {

    ss.insertSheet(cd);
    var itt = ss.getSheetByName(cd); 
    var ms = ss.getSheetByName("Master");
    var hlc = ms.getLastColumn();
    var headings = ms.getRange(1,1,1,hlc).getValues();
    itt.getRange(1,1,1,hlc).setValues(headings);
  }

  var MasterSheet = ss.getSheetByName(cd);
  var mlr = MasterSheet.getLastRow();
  var mlc = MasterSheet.getLastColumn();


  //check data already updated or not
  var NewDepositSlipNumber = Number(data[2]).toFixed(0);
  //Logger.log(Number(data[2]).toFixed(0));
  
  var olddata = MasterSheet.getDataRange().getValues();
  //Logger.log(olddata[1][2]);
  for(var i = 0; i<olddata.length;i++){
    if(olddata[i][2] == NewDepositSlipNumber){
        //Logger.log(i + 1);
        var status = 'Already Update'
        Logger.log(status);
        break;
    }
    else{
      var status = 'Not Update'
      //Logger.log(status);
    }
 }

 // count how many updated and how many not.
 if(status == 'Not Update'){
   na = na + 1;
 } 
 else{
   aa = aa + 1;
 }

 if(status == 'Not Update'){
  MasterSheet.appendRow(data);
  Logger.log("Data Updated");
 }
  }
  
  //problem # 2:  if conversation length are long, it is not reaching there
    var lastscantime = threadsNew[0].getLastMessageDate();
    var master = ss.getSheetByName("Master");
    master.getRange("Z1").setValue(lastscantime);
    Logger.log(lastscantime);
    master.getRange("Z2").setValue(new Date());
    Logger.log(new Date());
    Logger.log("Total " + threadsNew.length + " found, out of which " + aa + " are already updated, while " + na + " are updated.");
}

function parseEmail001(message) {

  var replaces = [
    'Branch Code',
    'Branch Name',
    'Slip No',
    'BL Number',
    'Type Of Payment',
    'Customer Name',
    'Payer Bank',
    'Payer Bank Branch',
    'Transaction Type',
    'Amount',
    'Posting Date',
    'Value Date'
  ];

  return message.split('\n').slice(0, replaces.length)
    .map((c,i) => c.replace(replaces[i], '').trim());

}
```

This script is working fine but I have two problems:

1. I placed three filters in query 1) from 2) subject 3) after
   but sometimes it gives me emails that are from the same ID but different subject.
2. as per my observation, and I verified it by using debug mode if the conversation length is long I guess more than 30 it will not reach the end part of the script. it skipping my last step as I also marked it in the above script. and if conversation length is less it works smoothly.

explanation: in other words, from morning to evening it's working fine after every five minutes, but the next day it gets the problem, then I manually update my spreadsheet master sheet Z1 value as of today's date and time, then it works fine till tonight.

Comment: Can you share your sheet?

Comment: it's difficult for me to share my sheet as it contains confidential data.

Comment: regarding 2nd problem, I tried to move this code before looping emails, and its work, so for learning purpose I want to know that why it's not reaching till the end? is there any timeout limit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might be reaching a [script limitation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/quotas#current_limitations). Possibly the custom function runtime.But it can be any, you should see an error if it didn't finish.

Comment: there is no error in the log, and loop end before completing thread.length

Comment: Without your sample sheet, its impossible to reproduce. Try wrapping the problematic function call within a try-catch block and see if you get anything?